# Page is not accessible when I close Webmatrix

Tags: iis-7, webmatrix

I have a server (`devserv`) with Webmatrix installed. Under settings, I modified the URL so it's now `http://devserv:8888`.
That allows me to access the 2 sites that I'm working on.
However, that works only I have Webmatrix open. When I close it, the sites are not accessible.
They are not accessible locally either, btw, but I'm giving you the full picture just in case.

The error that I get is that the `web.config` cannot be read to do insufficient rights.

However, all domain users have the right to read and execute on the folder that contains the sites and I checked the rights go down the tree.

So the question is what am I doing wrong, and why when Webmatrix is open, then there is no problem.

This is a Windows 2008 R2 server Standard and IIS is 7.5.7600.16385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMatrix only starts up the IIS Express server for a given site while you are editing it (with WebMatrix open).  When you close WebMatrix, we shut down the IIS Express process.  IIS Express is really only meant to be used during development time - if you want the site to continue to be available, I'd suggest installing full IIS on it, and using WebMatrix publishing to push your files to the server with Web Deploy.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: It helps a lot!!! Would you know of an automated process to deploy internally to a server with IIS instead of to the web?

Comment: Typically this is the space of 'continuous deployment' :)  Usually people will do automated deployments after checking into source control, or as part of a nightly build.  Are you using source control?  If so, which one?  Are you running nightly builds? If so, which build tool are you using?

Comment: Justin, no nightly builds or source control. My application doesn't change that often. I'm a one man show here and this is just of of the things I do. That said, if you would be forced to recommend the simplest source control system that you are aware of... Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I would just set up Web Deploy / IIS on your internal server.  Then, when you want to push a copy, you can just use WebMatrix Publish to push your changes to the server.  If you get fancy, you could automate that process using the Windows Task Scheduler and the Web Deploy command line tools :)